# Tomcat Not Running Fresh 'Hello World' Netbeans Web App - Stuck @ 'Please Wait...'

Tags: java, maven, web, tomcat, netbeans

I've just created a fresh web application in Netbeans. Project builds fine. However, once I hit run Tomcat starts up fine, but no browser window opens.

If I go under Services > Apache Tomcat or TomEE > Web Applications I can see 'Please wait...' where my project name should be.

Why isn't Tomcat running my project. If I go to localhost/port I can see that Tomcat is running fine but the project is stuck on 'Please wait...'.

I'm using Tomcat 9, Java 16, Java EE 8 Web, Netbeans 12, and Maven Compiler 3.1. If anything else is need to help then please leave comment or message me and I'll get right back

I can't seem to see any issue in the server logs either. What is the issue?

'Please Wait': https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3AOI.png

Server Log: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT1dU.png

Can't embed images as I don't have enough rep.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Maven.

Comment: Update your question with all of the following: [1] State the version of NetBeans being used. (NetBeans 12.4 is the only version which supports JDK 16.) [2] Embed the server log content as text. Log files should always be presented in text form rather than as images. [3] Also show the content of the NetBeans log file during the build and deployment of your application to Tomcat. You can view the data in that log using **View > IDE Log**, which displays its content in the **Output** window in NetBeans.

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask] and skomisa's comment.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how to close the question so I'll answer it myself in case others run into same issue. Problem was simply that the version of Netbeans (12.0 LTS) I was using wasn't compatible with JDK 16 as @skomisa mentioned in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: You did the right thing; answered your own question, and marked it as accepted.